# How to load webview links inside this same webview Android

Tags: android, web-applications, webview, hyperlink

I want to build a Android webApplication without PhoneGap, and i have a problem : when i click on a link it open the android default browser... : so how to load webview links inside this same webview Android ?

Here is my code :

```
package com.example.mobilewebview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;
//import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.google.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to intercept the URL links that your `WebView` might have in order to do your custom implementation.

You have to create a `WebViewClient` for your `WebView` and then override the `public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method to achieve such a thing.

Sample code:

```
//web view client implementation
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        //do whatever you want with the url that is clicked inside the webview.
        //for example tell the webview to load that url.
        view.loadUrl(url);
        //return true if this method handled the link event
        //or false otherwise
        return true;
    }
}}

//in initialization of the webview:
....
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
....
```

Tell me if that helps.