# i have a webview app and facing that when i click on Hyperlink then it open in default browse

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview app and facing a problem that 
when I click on Hyperlink then it opens in default browser.

But I want to open that link in same webview.
How to open it in same webview.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/abc/index.html");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("file:///android_asset/abc/index.html")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just return `false` unconditionally from the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method, and remove everything else there. You really don't even need to subclass `WebViewClient` if that's all you need it for: `myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load webview links inside this same webview Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552648/how-to-load-webview-links-inside-this-same-webview-android)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like,

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false; 
    } 
});
```

Return `false` in all cases.

Comment: There's no need to call `view.loadUrl(url);`.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. you have added a WebViewClient also..

then try it in this way...

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});
```

this should work for you..

Comment: There's no need to call `view.loadUrl(url);`.