# When clicked to a page it opens in the browser. I want it in the app

Tags: android

When I try to run this code in Android Studio it opens the pages in the app, my phone also open the pages in the app when clicking. However, other users say that when they click to open a page it opens in their browsers. How can i solve this problem?

```js
package com.klasspor.klasspor;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://m.klasspor.com");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, you run loading in your `WebView` in `onCreate` of your `MainActivity`, not on click of some item.
So, when users click some link in your app, sure they will open it in browser.
Also, please post full code of your Activity - which items click should open link in `WebView`?

Or, maybe, you need something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552648/how-to-load-webview-links-inside-this-same-webview-android).

Comment: Thank you for your 'this' question.

Comment: You welcome ;) If this would help, you could upvote my answer and/or mark it as correct. Thanks.